# получение токена в yandex money используя python 3 и flask

Tags: python, flask, yandex-money

Пытаюсь получить токен для моего приложения ,использующего яндекс деньги.

```
import flask
from yandex_money.api import Wallet, ExternalPayment
from yandex_money import api

from flask import request

code1='B955C648182E9C6FF938207129C9E2....'

scope1 = ['account-info', 'operation-history']
auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id=code1,redirect_uri='www.myurl', scope=scope1)

scope = ['account-info', 'operation-history']

auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(code,'www.myurl', scope)

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def ymon():


    token = api.Wallet.get_access_token(client_id=token1,
                                        code=flask.request.args['code'],
                                        redirect_uri='www.myurl')

    return render_template('ya.html', token=token) #,template_folder='path')
```

html файл:

```
<html>



<body>
<td>{{ token }}</td>
</body>
</html>
```

получаю ошибку :

```
-Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

пробовал без шаблона :

```
  @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def ymon():


        token = api.Wallet.get_access_token(client_id=token1,
                                            code=flask.request.args['code'],
                                            redirect_uri='www.myurl')

        return token
```

помогите , пожалуйста , разобраться

Answer (score 0):

```
auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id=code1,redirect_uri='www.myurl', scope=scope1)
```

Этой строчкой вы получили url.
Тепер нужно перенаправить пользователя на эту url.
Что б он подтвердил те права на операции, что вы запросили.

Ответ прийдет на redirect_uri.
На момент написания ответа в пакете yandex_money есть ошибка. и что б все корректно работало нужно добавить
'&response_type=code'

Вот так:

```
auth_url = Wallet.build_obtain_token_url(client_id=code1,redirect_uri='www.myurl', scope=scope1) + '&response_type=code'
```

И тогда юрл-ка будет корректной. Надеюсь поправят